# iPhone support Multiple Languages

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

In my project, I need to support the Korean language. How is it possible - can anyone explain briefly with example, whether it is possible or not?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898308/how-simplify-iphone-localization

Comment: Also why not just do this? Plenty of information: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=iphone+localization

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly possible.

You just tell Xcode to add a Korean localization to any of your application's localizable resources that need to change for that language.  (Localizable resources include strings files, xib files, and potentially any images containing text.)  Xcode will create a copy of your existing English resource, which you can modify and replace with a Korean-language equivalent.

Then when your application is run on a device with Korean set as its preferred language, iOS will automatically use the Korean resources intead of the English ones to present the application's user interface.  If you have used good localization code practices (such as using NSLocalizedString to reference strings you present in the user interface) you shouldn't have to change any of your code to support different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Check this guide on how to localize your apps for iPhone: http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/