# Memory management in iOS Localization with .strings file

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, localization, localizable.strings

Earlier i had posted this: [What should be the better way for localizing iOS project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332342/what-should-be-the-better-way-for-localizing-ios-project)

Now I have done projects for both the ways and I am satisfied with the answers given over there.

In .strings file localization, if there  is a username UILabel then instead of assign values in .nib itself, we do create an IBOutlet for that and in .m file we are assigning values. So is there any extra memory consumed by that IBOutlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to have **IBOutlet**  for accessing it **.m** file for the purpose of modifying the appearance. It will not give you any extra memory overheard, Even if you declare it with `retain` it will just increase the `retainCount` BUT don't forget to release it in `dealloc` if you retain the `UILabel`.

Comment: Hi I have not set property for that IBOutlet, do I require to set it up?

Comment: @ mrunal: yes,For changing the text of UILabel.